# Database table design when an entry has a work flow

Tags: database-design

There is a table info_table, each row in this table has a work flow, they must passed by step1, step2 ..., every step will save some columns value,  there will be too many columns so that hard to read, is there a better way to design it? thank you!

Comment: If you're not searching by this columns, you can save it all in one xml column

Comment: @RomanPekar, I need present the columun data to user

Comment: well, after you get a data from XML from column, you can parse it into values. You can also use EAV (entity - attribute - value) model to store dynamic number of columns. So you make a table like Field_Name, Field_Value and store values there.

Comment: @RomanPekar, Is OA System often design like this?  It sounds complex.

Comment: well I've designed some parts of our system that way and it works well, but I can't really say if such a pattern are used often in work flow systems. I depends on what are you planning to do with stored data. Are you planning to use it in business logic or just show it to users?

Comment: @RomanPekar, in logic, not only store data, also logic wise.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a table with a row for each step of the workflow for a task

eg:

```
task    step    details
1       1       blah
1       2       whatever
2       1       etc
```

Comment: You mean all steps save in one table, having a foreign key reference to base info table.

Comment: I mean a table with a row for each step, rather than a column for each step.

Comment: but some steps maybe don't have same column name and same column meaning.